# Qt Qml - drawing controls into TextEdit

Tags: qt, qml

I want to paint controls directly into `TextEdit`. It is easy, but the problem is i need to have space for them, so they are not painted over the text.

For example (the whole line is representing what will be shown in `TextEdit` and the highlighted code should be qml component):

Here is button: `button` and here is text again.

I need somehow to reserve space for the `button` between `Here is button:` and `and here is text again`.

It looks like Qt qml doesn't provide any way how to specify font metrics (in that case i could ask the component what it's width is and just add
one whitespace char with properly setup font and its metrics and than 
specify component coordinates so it is painted exactly where the space is).

I did it in Java SWT, because SWT StyledText allows to setup metrics for each character. So this is example how it should look.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML markup in TextEdit

```
TextEdit {
    textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
    text: "<font size=50>text</font>"
}
```

Comment: this will increase even the height of the line

Comment: i tried div with margin already, but div is always rendered on new line

Comment: @Krab try `text <img width = 50> text`

Comment: looks it will work with img, but it shows some warning about invalid img resource. I think the right solution will be something with this http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/richtext-layouts.html

Comment: @Krab if you want supress warning, use `<img src=qrc:/transparentImage.png width = 50 height = 1>`. And add transparentImage.png to resource file

Comment: @Krab If you want to add simple button into TextEdit, I think the right solution will be add HTML image is created as link and using linkActivated signal, instead of drawing control over TextEdit. if you want add more complex control, then I agree with you, right solution will be somephing with text layout

Comment: I found the solution, it is just about implementing one interface and little setup. https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTextObjectInterface.html
The problem is the drawObject method isn't called if i am using TextEdit in qml. With QTextEdit it normally works.